# SSL Certificate Validation for cross server communications

Tags: php, python, security, ssl, public-key-encryption

I am writing a python based monitoring agent and a php based service that aggregates all of the agent's data.. I want to be able to securely validate that the server is authorized to talk to the agent.

My thoughts were to exchange SSL certificates between the agent and the server and do some sort of validation with the public/private keys. Much like puppet does/did with agents and puppetmaster.

The agent runs a small python web service on port 8089, and accepts connections from a whitelisted hostname (srv01). This web service receives commands and does various stuff on the "client" system in which the agent runs on.

What would be the best way to authenticate and authorize this cross communication from server->agent:8089. Initially I was going to generate a unique sha256 hash and store it both on the agent and server and just do a comparison of this. Is this acceptable, or is there something else I should be looking into?

I would assume a basic flow of getting this process to work would be..

1. generate a keypair on the server
2. copy the private key to the agent via ssh or scp
3. server communicates to the agent via http port 8089, passing along its public key
4. agent validates the public key against the private key
5. if the validation is successful, the agent goes and does stuff.

as an FYI, These servers are firewalled off from the rest of the world in an enterprise environment.

Comment: This is more a design question than a programming question and might be better asked at security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thanks ill post it there.

Comment: Ask an admin to migrate it rather than cross posting.